# Aggregating on a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

**1. I have an elastic search schema below.**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "process_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "user_info": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "first_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "place": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. I have added the below documents to the index.**

```
POST processes/_bulk 
  {"index":{"_id":1}}
{"process_id": "123", "user_info": [{"first_name": "A", "last_name": "B","place":"London"},{"first_name": "C", "last_name": "D","place":"Moscow"}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"process_id": "123", "user_info": [{"first_name": "C", "last_name": "B","Place":"Delhi"},{"first_name": "A", "last_name": "D","Place":"Bangalore"}]}
```

**3. I wanted to search for process_id as 123,** first_name as A and last_name as B, and and aggregate on Place of the user_info. I am trying to do it as below.

```
{   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "process_id:123"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user_info",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "user_info.first_name:A AND user_info.last_name:B"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }   },   "aggs": {
    "user_info": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "user_info"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_info.place": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_info.place"
          }
        }
      }
    }   } }
```

The result returns the first document correctly. However, the aggregate on the field place returns both London and Moscow. However, I want London to be returned as the output. I am not sure how to proceed with this. I have tried Nested Filter Search Aggregation as well but no success on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation applies to the entire document and not just the `nested types`, hence you see both `places`. However, for your case since you want to know what nested document matches - you can use [Inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "process_id:123"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "user_info",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "user_info.first_name:A AND user_info.last_name:B"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Above query should give you the inner hits like below:

```
 "_source" : {
          "process_id" : "123",
          "user_info" : [
            {
              "first_name" : "A",
              "last_name" : "B",
              "place" : "London"
            },
            {
              "first_name" : "C",
              "last_name" : "D",
              "place" : "Moscow"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "user_info" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.3862944,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "t1",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "user_info",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.3862944,
                  "_source" : {
                    "first_name" : "A",
                    "last_name" : "B",
                    "place" : "London"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: there is an issue with the approach you have suggested. If we do pagination limiting only 10 records per page,  It is not possible to get all the inner hits

Comment: Each Document will have its _Own Inner Hits_. Inner Hits are not global on all results

Comment: Yes. correct. That is not what I needed. I want something like an aggregation that works on the whole dataset specified in the query